# Decorating the class or the dispatch() method?

Tags: django

Yesterday I had a [Stackoverflow question about putting a permissioning check on a class-based-view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46250302/clumsy-repeat-myself-django-permission-check/46251377#46251377).  The solution seem(s) to be incorporating a `PermissionDeniedMixin`.  It also looks like I could try [`UserPassesTestMixin` from Django-braces](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27825209/3556757).

This made sense, but I was doing some background reading on the `dispatch()` method and stumbled onto [this part of the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/class-based-views/intro/#decorating-the-class):

> To decorate every instance of a class-based view, you need to decorate
>   the class definition itself. To do this you apply the decorator to the
>   dispatch() method of the class.

Why would I need or choose to decorate the instances with the permission mixins rather than the class itself?

Answer (score 0):

The main reason to write a mixin instead of a decorator is that mixins are classes and therefore extensible. If I want to slightly modify the behavior of `LoginRequiredMixin.handle_no_permission`, for example, it's easy enough to write a new class that extends `LoginRequiredMixin`, override `handle_no_permission`, and use that modified class instead. Being a function, the `login_required` decorator is not as straightforward to customize.